# In Active Record (Rails), how to select a sum of a column from a has_many relation with every parent record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, aggregate-functions

Considering this model:

```
User:
  id: int

Valuable:
  id: int
  user_id: int
  value: int
```

User has many Valuables.

Now here's the thing. I want to use ActiveRecord to select multiple users with any query, after which I want to be able to see the sum of all their valuables, **without having to do N+1 queries.**

So, I want to be able to do this:

```
# @var ids [Array] A bunch of User IDs.
User.where(id: ids).each do |u| 
  puts "User ##{u.id} has total value of #{u.total_value}
end
```

and it should do 1 (or max 2) queries and not instantiate all Valuables. I tried playing around with `select('*, SUM(valuables.value) as total_value).joins(valuables)`, but with no luck. I'm using PostgreSQL

If at all possible, I would like this to happen automatically (e.g. using `default_scope`) and I still want to be able to use `includes`.

**UPDATE:** Sorry I haven't been clear about this. (Actually, I did write it). I **do not** want all valuables to be instantiated. I would like to have PostgreSQL do the calculation for me.

**UPDATE:** What I mean is, I want to depend on PostgreSQL's SUM method to get the total sum in the resultset. I thought my effort in using `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` made that clear. I don't want any data or record objects from the Valuables table be part of the result, because it consumes too much memory and calculating the fields using Ruby simply uses too much CPU and takes too long.

Comment: any 100 random users ?

Comment: Any query. :) I'm just using the 100 users as an example. I want the SUM to be included in the query. Updated the question, thanks.

Comment: cool, what is `total_value` ?

Comment: `total_value` would be the sum of the 'value' field of all valuables related to that user. See the 'select' statement I tried to play around with, I defined it there. :)

Comment: what is the actual output you are looking for. `.includes` is fie, it is also a Postgresql query internally.

Comment: It's not the output that concerns me, I understand I can do this on a small scale with eager loading. It's the way I want to get it. I've got a very large resultset, so I can't afford to either have all Valuable instances in my application, and I can't afford to do `valuables.each_with_object(0){|v,o| o+=v.value}`, it takes too long and too much CPU time. I realize this really is an SQL question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In raw SQL you want something like this:

```
SELECT users.*, SUM(valuable.value) AS values_sum
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN valuables ON users.id = valuables.user_id
GROUP BY users.id
```

So to translate this in a ActiveRecord query would look like this:

```
User.select('users.*, SUM(valuables.value) AS total_value')
    .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN valuables ON users.id = valuables.user_id')
```

Note that you are not actually selecting any columns from `valuables`.

```
[10] pry(main)> @users = User.select('users.*, SUM(valuables.value) AS total_value').joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN valuables ON users.id = valuables.user_id')

  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT users.*, SUM(valuables.value) as total_value FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN valuables ON users.id = valuables.user_id
=> [#<User:0x007f96f7dff6e8
  id: 8,
  created_at: Fri, 05 Feb 2016 20:36:34 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 05 Feb 2016 20:36:34 UTC +00:00>]
[11] pry(main)> @users.map(&:total_value)
=> [6]
[12] pry(main)>
```

However the "default_scope" and "I still want to be able to use includes" requirements might be a little tall unless you want to [manually load the associations](https://mrbrdo.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/manually-preloading-associations-in-rails-using-custom-scopessql/).

Comment: This is the answer that I was looking for. I noticed the mistake I made was to select `*` instead of – what is correct – `users.*`.

Comment: If you have a lot of read operations on `users` but not so many write operations on `valuables` you might want to setup a callback on the `has_many :valuables` association and use it to update a `total_value` in the users table. Will be slightly faster and you can just pull and join User however you want.

Comment: Something like this: `UPDATE users SET total_value = val.s FROM (SELECT sum(valuables.value) AS s FROM valuables WHERE user.id = :user_id ) AS val WHERE users.id = :user_id`

Comment: Yeah, I used to have something like that. For reasons beyond the scope of this question, I can't keep track of it in a different place in the database and trust that it will always be correct (unless I do it on the database level using a VIEW, but then I can't write to it).

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**:

```
hash = User.joins(:valuables).group('users.id').sum('valuables.value')
hash.each { |uid, tval| puts "User ID #{uid} has total value #{tval}." }
```

Note that the hash will only contain entries for users that have valuables. To get all users (even those without valuables), you can use `includes` instead of `joins`.

**Method 2**:

```
value_hash = Valuable.group(:user_id).sum(:value)
all_user_ids = User.pluck(:id)

all_user_ids.each do |uid| 
  tval = value_hash[uid] || 0
  puts "User ID #{uid} has total value #{tval}."
end
```

I would go with **Method 1** and `includes`.

**Edit:** After better understanding the question:

```
user_columns = User.column_names.join(', ')

users = User.
        includes(:valuables).
        group('users.id').
        select("#{user_columns}, sum(valuables.value) AS total_value")

users.each { |u| puts "User ID #{user.id} has #{u.total_value} total value." }
```

Comment: Actually, I think you need `eager_loads` instead of `includes` as includes may not know to LEFT JOIN instead of doing a separate query. (Maybe it does, I find its intelligence to be unpredictable). This is the closest to  an answer I've got yet. I can get the output (which is great), but I can't still get the `total_value` directly from a `user` object. I could hack it so by keeping the hash in a class variable of the User model (which is very ugly but could work). What I ideally want is to query it to a separate row in the resultset using `select`, so Rails hydrates it into the User objects.

Comment: @PelletenCate, I misunderstood. I didn't know want the `total_value` to be an attribute of the `user` instance. I've added an edit to my answer which should do the job.

Comment: AH, thanks! You were just after @max, but I appreciate your answer and update. I got it working just using `users.*` instead of using user_columns. Does it have any advantage doing it your way?

Comment: @PelletenCate no problem; it can potentially be helpful when the table being joined has some similarly named columns. But you should be OK with `users.*` in most cases.